# Drawing a data structure

Tags: c#, architecture, solution, b-tree

I am creating an implementation of a data structure (B-Tree) for learning purposes.

I want to put the classes required into it's own assembly and only reference and use the bare minimum of .NET-Namespaces there. Of course I also hide as much data and code through private or internal as possible so the class looks clean.

While developing, debugging and so on I do draw a graphical representation of the tree onto a bitmap and dump those onto disk, but to do that I need System.Drawing, ...2D, ...Imaging, ...Text as namespaces. Those should NOT be part of the pure data structure code. This drawing code should be "somewhere else"

I am done with the development, everything works and draws perfect. I can see my tree grow and shrink as list of pictures on my disk, but I am not happy with the solution layout. I think I am messing through the concerns of each assembly too much.

At the moment the drawing code is part of the windows forms code, and I put quite some public properties into the data structure class to allow the drawing code to get values needed when drawing.

Now how would I create a project, class and assembly that can draw the tree to a bitmap without compromising the pure data structure class?

The tree would raise events (or call delegates?) whenever it determines it changed it structure and should be re-displayed. The assembly responsible for drawing needs these calls, but also needs some access into the private details of the tree to display it.

Reflection is something I am somewhat familiar with but it sounds a bit over the top.

I could do DEBUG and RELEASE builds, and encapsulate the sections for drawing with conditional compiling (##IFDEBUG ?) but that still means I need to include a lot of code (and compile hints) into the data structure code.

Partial classes in the same assemble? Still needs the reference to `System.Drawing`.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks
Ralf

Comment: You do need (at least) 3 projects: 1) data structure, 2) Draw, 3)A main to call the other two. You can "glue" the projects/assemblies by dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard problem in general but one thing you could do is expose only `internal` members to your drawing code so that other code does not need to know of their existence. You can use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to create a "friend" assembly that is able to access internal members of another. Then, you can put the drawing code into a second assembly and keep the primary one pristine.